Why email not sending through HTML site using php?
I am trying to send emails through my HTML site using PHP, but unfortunately, it is not working.
What is the actual problem? Please can anybody help?>
This is my HTML code:
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name*" required aria-label=".form-control-lg example">
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="phone" id="phone" type="number" placeholder="Your Phone No" aria-label=".form-control-lg example">
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email*" required aria-label=".form-control-lg example">
<textarea class="form-control pt-4" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" rows="3"></textarea>
<div class="btn_group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn olive">Send Mail</button>  
</div>

and my PHP code:
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message \n Phone: $phone";
$recipient = "recipientmail@gmail.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";

?>

First check whether you have configured your server for email sending. Then, does recipientmail@gmail.com exists.

Don't spoof your emails as being from a random email address supplied by the user. You don't have permission to send email as if you are them. Impersonation attempts like this will make your email server get blocked. Use a fixed From address matching your mailserver's domain. Include the supplied email in the message body and/or Reply-To header instead. See the duplicate question (in the blue box above) for more details
